# Open app from associated domains and swipe pop view controller

Tags: ios, swift

When i open app from associated domain links, i have an issue with swipe for pop view controller - is isn't work. Is it possible to do technically or impossible ?

```
 func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL,
                  options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> 
  Bool {
        let deepLinkStringUrl = "https://" + url.host! + url.path

        self.postsInteractor.getPostBy(url: deepLinkStringUrl,
                                            completion:
              { (deepLinkPost) in

                 if let navController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
                                                                        as? UINavigationController {


                    let detailsVc = navController.storyboard?
                                                .instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String.init(describing: PostDetailsViewController.self))
                                                                                            as! PostDetailsViewController
                        detailsVc.post = deepLinkPost
                        navController.pushViewController(detailsVc, animated: true)
                    }
                }) { (errorString) in
                    print(errorString)
                } 
     }
```

Comment: hoe do you open your domain link? I mean, do you use a deep link?

Comment: Yes, it is deep and usual links. Init view controller and get navigation controller work correctly, like another screens with the same logic. I opened "Medium" app - there is not work similarly.

Comment: can you add the code for your deep link? and how do you try present/push your view? or don't you try it? and finally, it's posibble open a new view from a deep link, you can push or present and pass data

Comment: Attached some code

Comment: ok, do you have some code for detect your deep link?

Comment: Updated. How does this related to swipe for pop view controller's logic ?

Comment: Are you using storyboards and is there a SceneDelegate in your Xcode project?

Comment: There isn't a scene delegate

Comment: The Problem was related with AASA file. Thank you everybody for answers.